# Connecting to Azure VM over VPN service

Tags: virtual-machine, vpn, azure

I want to be able to run a VPN client on my desktop to establish a secure/anonymous connection to the Internet and then connect to my Azure VM. When I run Remote Desktop Connection, I get an error. Looks like the VM needs to be configured. Is there any tutorial out there that could show me how this is done?

Answer (score 0):

You should create a network before you create the VM. When you create the VM make sure the VM using the network you've created. I think it in the last step before you assign the port forwarding when you create the VM.

1. Create the Network in Azure.
2. Define address space.
3. Create VM.
4. Define Point to Site VPN at the Network.
5. Download the client (windows only?)
6. Connect.

perhaps this could help:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dn133792.aspx